# BottomNavigationView's text size and circular reveal animation on click

Tags: android, android-design-library, bottomnavigationview

I started using the new `BottomNavigationView` of design support library.

I wanted to achieve below items but couldn't get any code snippets.

1. How I can change the bottom navigation view's text size?
2. How I can get the circular reveal animation as shown in material design guidelines(as in the below link)? Can anyone provide sample code snippets for this?

https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/600/1*uMnDyq7fTZ3KDu2BteuIxw.gif

Comment: can you post an image what youre looking for?

Comment: Updated the question with gif image link

Comment: this seems as what you want ? https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation